# UI doesn't get updated sometimes in Android

Tags: android, user-interface, scrollview

I am trying to populate data in UI fetched through REST service. The data comes up everytime but the UI doesn't get populated sometimes. The UI is kind of listing but listview is not being used. There's a ScrollView which has LinearLayout as its child and then row views are added to the linearlayout. There are times when UI just doesn't get updated even if the data is passed to it.

```
private void showData(List list) {  
if(list != null && list.isEmpty()) {
    mNoData.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    mNoData.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    final LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.details_layout);

    findViewById(R.id.details_progress).setVisibility(View.GONE);

    linearLayout.removeAllViews();
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView = null;
    TextView txtName = null;
    Button buttonPlay = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        rowView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_view, null);
        txtName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.row_view_name);
        buttonPlay = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.row_view_button_play);
        final Item item = (Item) list.get(i);
        rowView.setTag(i) ;
        txtName.setText(item.getName());
        final RecentItem recentItem = RecentsManager.getInstance().getRecentItemFromRefID(item.getId());

        if (recentItem !=null) {
            buttonPlay.setText(getString("Resume"));
            buttonPlay.requestFocus();
        }

        buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (recentItem!=null) {
                    //do some action
                } else {
                    //do some action
                }

                finish();
            }
        });

        final int tag = (Integer) rowView.getTag() ;
        rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //do some action
            }
        }) ;

        txtName.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //do some action
            }
        });

        buttonPlay.setId(i);

        if(i < list.size())
            buttonPlay.setNextFocusDownId(i+1);

        linearLayout.addView(rowView);

        if (i == 0) {
            buttonPlay.requestFocus();
            buttonPlay.setNextFocusUpId(mButtonReminder.getId());

            if(mButtonReminder != null) {
                mButtonReminder.setNextFocusDownId(buttonPlay.getId());
            }   
        } else {
            buttonPlay.setNextFocusUpId(i-1);
        }
    }
}
}
```

I have even checked the linearlayout children's count and the count is always equal to list size which means rows are also being added to it but it just doesn't show up on the UI.

What can be the issue?

Comment: Can someone point out what can be the issue here ? Sometimes, the number of rows that needs to be added is around 400. Can this be an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by doing certain changes as adding fillViewPort="true" for scrollview. Also, there was a background thread which was trying to update the UI because of which UI thread was breaking. This didn't resulted in a crash but the UI updation didn't happened. With these two changes it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

you are using condition

```
if(list != null && list.isEmpty()) {
    mNoData.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

change it to

```
if(list == null || list.isEmpty()) {
    mNoData.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: I think the null check is necessary before calling isEmpty method on its instance. As I said the data is received but only it is not visible on the screen.

Comment: @mobiledev show your  layout. As you said child views are added in linear layout, so I think the problem in your layout.